# In Game Maker Studio, how do I make a sound play only once when I jump on a block?

Tags: game-maker, sound-effects

In my Game Maker Studio game, jumping on a musical block should play a note. Currently, if I step on it, the note keeps repeating.

How can I avoid that? I only want the note to play once.

Comment: Could you summarise what your game code looks like right now? In what event are you playing the sound effect?

Answer (score 1):

The function audio_play_sound as a third parameter, 'loop'. If this is set to true, then your sound will loop. Try setting this to false.

audio_play_sound(index, priority, loop);

Reference:
http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/game%20assets/sounds/audio_play_sound.html

Comment: I obviously know that, what is happening is it keeps playing again and again because it is executing it in the step event, every step it keeps playing.

Comment: I don't know Gamemaker, but can't you bind the sound to the jump end collision code? Or store the block that played a sound last and only play the sound if that block is no longer the stored sound block? Handling it in the collidion would be best I guess as it decouples it from your main game logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a boolean condition before playing the sound then making it false when a collision happens.

Something like this:

```
if (place_meeting(x+1,y,objPlayer) || place_meeting(x,y+1,objPlayer) ||
    place_meeting(x-1,y,objPlayer) || place_meeting(x,y-1,objPlayer) &&
    noLooping == true) {

    audio_play_sound(index, priority, false);
    noLooping = false;

} else {
    noLooping = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this--

if !audio_is_playing(snd_xyz)
{
 audio_play_sound(snd_xyz,..,..)
}

I also had this problem once, though i could not solve it completely. The above code did some good though

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem without using any additional variables, just collision checking function. Assuming that in the real world when someone jumps you hear a sound only in the very moment contact with the ground occurs, I managed to get the following code which checks for collision in the current position and in the previous one. Objects name are only indicative:

```
var curr_coll = place_meeting(x,y+1,oBlock);
var prev_coll = place_meeting(xprevious,yprevious+1,oBlock);
```

Variables `curr_coll` is a boolean value that tells us if there's a collision with a block underneath the player at the *current* position. As well, `prev_coll` does the same, but assuming the player position in the previous game step.

So, we can have four different cases (CC: `curr_coll`, PC: `prev_coll`):

- **CC = 0, PC  = 0 :** no collision both currently and previously, so the player has jumped and is in mid-air;
- **CC = 0, PC = 1 :** no collision now, but collision detected in the previous step. This means the player has just performed a jump;
- **CC = 1, PC = 0 :** there's a collision at the current step, and no collision a game step before. So, the player was in mid-air and is currently hitting the ground. *Now* you can play the proper musical sound;
- **CC = 1, PC = 1 :** there's always a collision with a given `oBlock` or whatever object, so the player is walking on top of it.

That said, we can write our code to check for the needed values. You can use both a `switch` statement, or a chain of `if`s, depending on your purpose. If we want to just play a sound only when landing on a musical key, we can write:

```
if ( (curr_coll==1) && (prev_coll==0) )
{
    audio_play_sound(sndNoteD,1,false);
}
```

So, our full code will be:

```
/// Step Event for object 'oPlayer' ///
var curr_coll = place_meeting(x,y+1,oBlock);
var prev_coll = place_meeting(xprevious,yprevious+1,oBlock);

// Play sound if walk/jump on a musical block
if ( (curr_coll==1) && (prev_coll==0) )
{
    audio_play_sound(sndNoteD,1,false);
}
```

As commented in code, this code may work both for jumping on top of or walking onto a musical block. If you want to distinguish between walking or jumping, you need to perform a couple of more checks, but nothing hard.